# NVD3 Sparkline not rendering correctly from CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nvd3.js, sparklines

I'm trying to use NVD3 with d3.js to make a simple sparkline. I've successfully created several sparklines with .csv data, but when I tried to use a different data set, it gave a very strange looking sparkline. See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/nuernber/6064535/4ad8fe4c34c9013ec13819820bcdb12498806e77). If I change the first data value from 92 to 0, it successfully shows the sparkline.

Is this a bug in NVD3 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem might be with the new set of data you are trying to pass, if you could update the question with the data, someone will be able to help.

Comment: The data is in the link I provided above ([this link](http://bl.ocks.org/nuernber/6064535/4ad8fe4c34c9013ec13819820bcdb12498806e77))

Comment: I see you are passing **data** into **datum()** , how does **data** look like when you are passing it ? I was hoping to see that, not the CSV representation.

Comment: Ah, I see! data was [{x: <Date obj>, y: "92"}, ...]. I needed to change y into a number, not a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the y values were strings. I changed

```
monthlyData.push({x: data[i].Month, y: data[i].Data});
```

to

```
monthlyData.push({x: data[i].Month, y: +data[i].Data});
```

so that the y value becomes a number. Here's [the updated version](http://bl.ocks.org/nuernber/6064535/7d92be8dcf53d6e6d68b6667ab95065d1ec72730).

Comment: It doesn't allow the person who posted the question to accept their own answer until 24 hours later...